# Baffling syntax error

Tags: reactjs, jsx

This is my React component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ThingsList extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            {this.props.things.map(thing => {
                <p> hello </p>
            })}
        )
    }
}

export default ThingsList
```

Error:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (8:8)

   6 |      
   7 |      return (
>  8 |          {this.props.things.map(thing => {
     |               ^
   9 |              <p> hello </p>
  10 |          })}
  11 |      )
```

I've been stuck on this for like an hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing free floating jsx in the middle of JavaScript. You either need to "begin" writing some proper jsx (which starts with an opening `<`) or just write normal JavaScript. Keep in mind though that you can't return an array of elements in render.

```
return (
  // need to create opening JSX tag which compiles to `React.createElement`
  <span>
    {this.props.things.map(thing => {
      return <p> hello </p>
    })}
  </span>
)
```

Comment: should be `return <p> hello </p>`

Comment: in all my two years of React, I've never done this and hence never ran into this issue - learned something new, thanks!! (will accept when it lets me)